# Syntax error : ng-messages='{{field}}.$error'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following error

Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{field}}.$error] starting at [{field}}.$error].

when I try to run the following code (form-field.html)

```
<div class='row form-group' ng-form="{{field}}" ng-class="{ 'has-error': {{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid }">
    <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'> {{ field | labelCase }} <span ng-if='required'>*</span></label>
    <div class='col-sm-6' ng-switch='required'>

        <input ng-switch-when='true' ng-model='record[field][0]' type='{{record[field][1]}}' class='form-control' required ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' />

        <div class='input-group' ng-switch-default>
            <input ng-model='record[field][0]' type='{{record[field][1]}}' class='form-control' ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' />
            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='remove(field)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span></button> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
***PROBLEM CODE LINE BELOW***
    <div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='{{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid' ng-messages='{{field}}.$error'>
        <p class='control-label' ng-message='required'> {{ field | labelCase }} is required. </p>
        <p class='control-label' ng-repeat='(k, v) in types' ng-message='{{k}}'> {{ field | labelCase }} {{v[1]}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code to replace the directive  in the following code:

```
<form-field record='contact' field='firstName' live='false' required='true'></form-field>
```

The problem is obviously Angular does not like the `ng-messages={{field}}.$error` and I can get rid of the error by changing it to

```
ng-messages='field.$error'
```

but then the error message in the next paragraph does not get displayed.
This code is from the TutsPlus Building a Web App from scratch with Angularjs which was released September 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you got this error is because you are probably using **angular version 1.4.1**; and if you followed the tutorial using bower install angular messages, which you installed the angular-messages 1.4.1 as well.
Because in **angular-messages 1.4.1**, ng-messages no longer interprets its attribute value properly (that is the **[issue#11616](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11616)** on angular.js github)

---

The solution that I learned from [@gkalpak](https://github.com/gkalpak) is:

```
<div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='{{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid' ng-messages="this.$eval(field)['$error']">
```

Comment: Thank you - most interesting. Did you get the "First Name is required" message working? I cannot get any output from {{ field | labelCase }} in ng-message='required'> {{ field | labelCase }} is required.

Comment: Yes, I got that working. Can you post the code after you changed?

Comment: ' <div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='{{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid' ng-messages="this.$eval(field)['$error']">
  <p class='control-label' ng-message='required'> {{ field | labelCase }} is required. </p>
  <p class='control-label' ng-repeat='(k,v) in types' ng-message='{{k}}'>{{ field | labelCase}} {{ v[1] }} is required.</p>
 </div>'

Comment: Thank you, your code works fine. I am still slightly confused about the {{ field | labelCase }} problem as your code only appears different in the last "is required" - but it works and that's what matters.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double curly braces in `ng-show` and `ng-messages`, you don't need them because both expect an expression.

That should work:

```
<div class='col-sm-4 has-error' 
    ng-show='field.$dirty && field.$invalid'
    ng-messages='field.$error'>
```

Comment: yes removing the double curlies from ng-show and ng-messages gets rid of the error message. Now how do I display the error message which is contained in "field" which has the value firstName and is run through labelCase to format it. I have tried removing the double curlies from "field | labelCase" but it does not display. Thank you.