# AngularJs: NgMessages will not accept curly braces

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to use ngMessages but have come across a problem when specifying the form element to attach.

I could use this and it would work fine -

```
ng-messages="FieldForm951.FormElement951.$error"
```

However, (as you might tell from my element names) I am creating a dynamic form so I can't specify the names of elements as easily as this.

This is what I would like to do,

```
ng-messages="FieldForm{{Questions[' + scope.$index + '].Id}}.FormElement{{.Questions[' + scope.$index + '].Id}}.$error"
```

Really the only important factor is that I want to be able to use curly braces to specify custom names. This exact code works fine with ng-show, ng-required and anything else I have tried, but not with ngMessages. I get an error 'Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token'.

I guess since ngMessages is a custom module it does not have the same functionality, but is there a way I could get around this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `.` here `{{.Questions`

Comment: {{}} will interpolate your expression into a string, except ng-messages is looking for an expression. I would group your FieldForms into an an array or object called 'FieldForms' instead of having the ID number in the name. Then you can just use [] selectors: `FieldForm[Questions[' + scope.$index + '].Id].element.$error`

Comment: You can try same with ng-form. Which is use for loading form's dynamically like ng-repeat etc..,

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that this is apparently a known bug.

See this thread: [Syntax error : ng-messages='{{field}}.$error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021464/syntax-error-ng-messages-field-error)

The accepted answer to the above question includes [this open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11616) for the bug, which I recommend subscribing to so that you know when you can go back to using ng-messages with more dynamic expressions for this use case instead of whatever workaround you choose (I personally am just using ng-show since that allows me to refer to my dynamically named ng-forms inside of curly braces, making things a good deal more readable at a glance).

Comment: Is there a workaround that can be used in the meantime?

Comment: I did manage to get around this issue in the end, but it won't be applicable to most people I Imagine. I'd need to look at my code (can't at the moment) but since all my html was being added through a directive I was able to do something like ng-messages="' + validationMessage(index) + '" then that function would return the name without any curly braces or anything. If that is of any use for you I can look at my code in more detail tomorrow and get back to you.